# How are Behave's decorators created/declared?

Tags: python, bdd, python-decorators, python-behave

I am currently using Behave (BDD for Python) and have been digging in the source code to understand how the `@given`, `@when` and `@then` decorators are being declared.

The farthest I've gone is to look at `step_registry.py` where I found the function `setup_step_decorators(context=None, registry=registry)` which appears to be doing the job.

However, I don't quite understand how these decorators are created since they don't appear to be explicitly declared in the source code in the form of a `def when(...):`.  I am under the impression that they are declared based on a list of strings (`for step_type in ('given', 'when', 'then', 'step'):`) that is then processed by a call to `make_decorator()`.

Can someone walk me through the code and **explain where/how these decorators are being declared**?

Here is where you can get access to the [source code of Behave](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/behave).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, let's start at the outside:

```
if context is None:
    context = globals()
for step_type in ('given', 'when', 'then', 'step'):
    step_decorator = registry.make_decorator(step_type)
    context[step_type.title()] = context[step_type] = step_decorator
```

I think it's the last line that confuses you.

Every module's global namespace is just a dictionary. The function `globals()` returns that dictionary. If you modify that dictionary, you create new module globals. For example:

```
>>> globals()['a'] = 2
>>> a
2
```

In this case, by default, `context = globals()`. So, for, say, the first `step_type`, you're effectively doing this:

```
>>> globals()['given'] = step_decorator
```

Answer (score 3):

They are injected into `globals()` around line 90 (at that point `context` is `globals()` because `context` is `None`):

```
# -- Create the decorators
def setup_step_decorators(context=None, registry=registry):
    if context is None:
        context = globals()
    for step_type in ('given', 'when', 'then', 'step'):
        step_decorator = registry.make_decorator(step_type)
        context[step_type.title()] = context[step_type] = step_decorator
```

You can do this yourself too (`globals()` works just like a regular dictionary):

```
>>> a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
>>> globals()['a'] = 5
>>> a
5
```

Comment: Almost the exact same example as me at the exact same time. But of course the _right_ number to use in such an example is 2, not 5. :)

Comment: @abarnert I noticed that, weird that we both thought of `'a'` there. Probably 42 is the best ([or maybe 3](http://iheartquotes.com/tags/monty_python))

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks a lot guys, that was exactly what I was looking for.  I tend to agree that the example is much easier to understand with 42 :)